# Why don't Anakin and Padme look like refugees in Attack of the Clones?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

In Star Wars Episode II, Attack of the Clones, Anakin and Padme travel to Naboo disguised as refugees.

But they are wearing elaborate clothing. Padme has 3 high quality suitcases and they have an astromech droid, R2D2, who serves them meals on their passage.

Certainly that paints them as anything but refugees, does it not?
[image][image]

Comment: Rich people aren't allowed to search refugee?

Comment: Why are you assuming the cases are all Padme's? Maybe Anakin is holding his own.

Comment: The mistake you are committing here is that you are imposing beliefs from your own culture, society and world upon that of another galaxy. What makes you think those are high quality stuff? Does a 21st century Lamborghini look like something only the rich in a galactic society would drive?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You get rich refugees. In fact probably a higher level of refugees in the rich population than the poor as the rich can afford to travel and (sadly for the poor) fewer places will turn them away. War is not unique to undeveloped parts of the world and money does not protect you but instead might make you a target.

The quality is hard to judge their wealth by as you don't know how much those clothes and cases would cost, cheap modern clothing would be exceptionally fine one thousand years ago.

Also an astromech droid is a utility device which a poor family might own for their work. Using a droid not designed for serving food to serve food would probably be a sign of a lack of wealth, like a farmer who uses his tractor as his car.

TLDR: it's hard to assess the wealth from an economy that we have almost no knowledge of.